# Loss of Head retention

Tags: sanitation

i’m having a problem with head retention in my latest brew. Is there anything I can do to improve the head once the bottle is opened ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I improve head retention?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-do-i-improve-head-retention)

Comment: There is also this: [How do I improve head retention](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/how-do-i-improve-head-retention)

Comment: Also this: [What causes head retention](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/16670/what-causes-head-retention)

Answer (score 2):

After you've opened the beer you can't improve its inherent head retention qualities, but you can give it a fighting chance by ensuring your glasses are totally free from any detergents which might prevent a head from forming. And before opening the bottle, give it plenty of time in the fridge to make sure as much of the co2 as possible is dissolved in the beer when you do open it.